# Any recommend pattern or strategies for data access from java to mongo db?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm just starting a project where I need to return POJOs from our mongo db.  I did a quick search and found a few mappers in development but nothing extremely solid.

What I'm looking for:

1) Ideally, as little additional code as possible to map POJO to mongodb (and vice versa)
2) Recommended strategy/pattern for access (regarding connection pooling, injecting configuration, etc)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys... that got me going in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I did a quick search and found a few mappers in development but nothing extremely solid.`

Yeah MongoDB is like 18 months old. Most of the "wrappers" for it have been written in the last 4 to 6 months, I think that you're going to have a rough time finding **extremely** solid. Instead you're going to find a lot of *"enthusiastically built"* and *"running on our prod system"*.

[NoRM](http://github.com/atheken/NoRM) is a .NET library for "POCO" to Mongo. There are several "POJO" wrappers listed on the [MongoDB website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center).  They will likely have their own details regarding connection pooling and configuration injection.

However, there's very little configuration to inject with Mongo, I mean, we're basically talking about one connection string here, maybe a "java-to-object" map, that's pretty much it. And most people do away with that last part by using conventions.

In terms of connection pooling, it's available "out-of-the-box" with the Java driver, so hopefully your POJO wrapper is leveraging it by default or tells you how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Several POJO mappers are listed in the MongoDB [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center)